# Does Microsoft Teams require Server/AD or any other services to operate?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I wonder if Microsoft Teams is stand-alone software or it needs to be integrated in Server, AD or other services ? 
also I wonder does it have any connection with Active Directory users or it is independent?

I run a little company, I want to give it a try, can we use the TEAMS software with simple installation and administration, excluding Server/AD?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Teams is a fully online service and requires a microsoft account. You can use your Office365 subscriptions email account, or create a personal microsoft account and use that.

No Active Directory/Server is required.

That said, if you have a terminal server that users login to, keep in mind that there is a Teams wide installer, which is a special edition to run on servers. You install that, and then, every time a user logs in, they will get teams installed in their account.